# Update the database from the GridView when the data source is a query

Tags: database, vb.net

I have SQL QUERY:
**SELECT T_DATA_LOG.ID, T_DATA_LOG.SerialNumber, T_DATA_LOG.Note, T_EVENT.Name
FROM T_DATA_LOG INNER JOIN T_EVENT ON T_DATA_LOG.ID_EVENT = T_EVENT.ID_EVENT;**

*Table T_DATA_EVENT is event catalog for T_DATA_LOG*

**I need update T_DATA_LOG.Note**

I have this program. If I work directly with a spreadsheet, it works. if I use a query (join two tables) as a data source, it doesn't work.

Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class

```
Dim connetionString As String
Dim connection As OleDbConnection
Dim adapter As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim cmdBuilder As OleDbCommandBuilder
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim changes As DataSet
Dim sql As String
Dim i As Int32

Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'connetionString = "Data Source=Server_Name\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;Trusted_Connection=True;"
    connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & "e:\tmp\KuKacka2.0.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    connection = New OleDbConnection(connetionString)
    'sql = "Select * from D_DATA_LOG" - This is Work, but I need view data from T_EVENT

    sql = "SELECT T_DATA_LOG.ID, T_DATA_LOG.SerialNumber, T_DATA_LOG.Note, T_EVENT.Name FROM T_DATA_LOG INNER JOIN T_EVENT ON T_DATA_LOG.ID_EVENT = T_EVENT.ID_EVENT;"

    Try
        connection.Open()
        adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection)
        adapter.Fill(ds)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub



Private Sub DataGridView1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Click
    DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Orange
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'NOTE:  for this code to work, there must be a PK on the Table
    Try
        cmdBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter)
        changes = ds.GetChanges()
        If changes IsNot Nothing Then
            adapter.Update(changes)
        End If
        MsgBox("Changes Done")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Please, give me an advice.
Thanks, David

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it doesn't work" ? An error message of some kind ?

Comment: Error: system.invalidoperationexception dynamic generate sql is not supported